# how to Rspec generate in rails?

Tags: rspec

how to rspec generate in rails?
i also install plugin for rspec..
i also install gem rspec,rspec-rails..
now what can i do??

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884033/ruby-on-rails-switch-from-test-unit-to-rspec to change your default generator forever.

Answer (score 23):

Came here with the same question, and Don's answer got me on the right path.  The generators however have : instead of _ in the name for Rails 3:

```
> rails g rspec:controller soa/user
      create  spec/controllers/soa/user_controller_spec.rb

> rails g rspec:scaffold soa/user
      create  spec/controllers/soa/users_controller_spec.rb
      create  spec/views/soa/users/edit.html.erb_spec.rb
      create  spec/views/soa/users/index.html.erb_spec.rb
      create  spec/views/soa/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb
      create  spec/views/soa/users/show.html.erb_spec.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    spec/helpers/soa/users_helper_spec.rb
      create  spec/routing/soa/users_routing_spec.rb
      invoke  rspec
      create    spec/requests/soa/soa_users_spec.rb
```

Annoyingly, these are not listed when you run `rails g` but they are available.

Answer (score 7):

In your config/application.rb :

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In config/application.rb, add this line of configuration code

```
 config.generators do |g|
       g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
       g.integration_tool :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => true
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've installed rspec there will be new generators available called `rspec_scaffold`, `rspec_model` and `rspec_controller` which work similarly to the normal rails generators except that instead of generating stub tests, they generate stub specs.