# Ruby on Rails: Switch from test_unit to rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, testunit

I'm going through a tutorial that has suggested using `rspec`, but I have already gone through a lot of default rails installation.  I really don't want to have to redo the installation at all.  Anyway, when I run

```
$ rails g integration_test named
```

I get

```
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/integration/named_test.rb
```

When I run `bundle`, various `rspec` gems are listed, but `test_unit` is not.  The tutorial seems to have rails invoke `rspec` instead of `test_unit` without doing anything additional. How do I get rails to use `rspec` with the integration test generator command?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In your `config/application.rb` file :

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

Now when you run your generators (example `rails generate scaffold post`), you get rspec test files. Remember to restart your server. For more information on generators see:

[RailsCasts #216 Generators in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3)

If you really want to use the integration_test generator you'll need to specifically modify the command:

```
rails g integration_test named --integration-tool=rspec
```

Comment: I had already done that .. what do you mean by restart the server?  It was never running.

Comment: i mean restarting spork or your test interface. If you have properly done that and execute 'rails g scaffold --help' you should be seeing 'rspec' as the default testing framework. Check my edit as well.

Comment: I updated the config/application.rb as you specified and ran `rails g scaffold --help` and it *still* says test_unit.  Is there something I need to do to rerun the configuration or some way to manually change these settings?

Comment: For future users wanting to go the other way, leaving this comment for completeness: Use the above answer with `g.test_framework :test_unit` .

Comment: how do I switch back? Can I use both generators at once?

Comment: with the Rails app I'm testing on 6.1 (not sure which version this became true...) ... this method no longer works and gives me `configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `test_framework' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00007fca9b924f10> (NoMethodError)` ; For Rails 6-- see other answer about the gem being in the :test group but not the :development group

Answer (score 73):

Working with **Rails 3.2.8** and **rspec-rails 2.11.4**, I discovered that my problem was in my Gemfile.  I had `rspec-rails` in the `:test` group but not the `:development` group.  Since Rails defaults to running in development mode (including when you're running generate), `rspec-rails` has to be in your `:development` group for it to hook into the generators.  Once I had that in place, everything worked fine.

Comment: +1 rspec-rails install as railitie https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec-rails.rb#L6-7 and configures itself as test framework and integration tool. So one can include the gem in a shared group in the gemfile ```group :development, :test do```

Comment: Still relevant 7 years later!

Answer (score 32):

As of Rails 3.2.12, follow these steps in order

```
rails new app_name --skip-test-unit
```

Add rspec-rails to your Gemfile in the development, test group

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Run `bundle install`

Run the generator

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

... and cleanup your existing test directory:

```
rm -Rf $RAILS_ROOT/test
```

Comment: This will works if the project is already created too. Just ignore the  `rails new` command.

Comment: Watch out using the `rm -Rf $RAILS_ROOT/test` command, you'll remove your mailer previews too...

Answer (score 9):

Came across this issue today. 
application.rb has to be updated with:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
  g.integration_tool :rspec
end
```

Comment: editing the application.rb file is no longer required, at least on Rails 3.2 with rspec-rails

Answer (score 8):

To use RSpec instead of default Test::Unit, run following command first

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

This command will create following folder/files

```
create  .rspec
create  spec
create  spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Now whenever you used generator to generate rails components like controller, model etc, it will create corresponding RSpecs.

Comment: This will not work (rails 4) if you don't have rspec in your Gemfile already.  See fontno's answer below.

Comment: how do I switch back? Can I use both generators at once?

Answer (score 3):

In config/application, add this code

```
 config.generators do |g|
       g.test_framework  :rspec
       g.integration_tool :rspec
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1. when create new rails app, skip TestUnit framework, or it will generate test_unit directory.

`$rails new your_app --skip-test-unit`

### 2. add below code to your_app/config/application.rb file:

`config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end`

### 3. add below code to your_app's Gemfile:

`group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end`

save it, and run `bundle install` to install rspec gem

### 4. Initialize the spec/ directory

`rails generate rspec:install`

more details, please refer: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Answer (score 1):

What I found that I did that some of the other methods works still is to check my spelling....I had what @tovodeverett had grouping rspec-rails with :development and :test but spelt development incorrectly. That fixed my issue but I was generating tests with test_unit instead of rspec.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rails g model Account
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140205052617_create_accounts.rb
      create    app/models/account.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/account_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/accounts.yml
$ rails d model Account
```

Running *script/rails generate rspec:install* does not add rspec as default framework. Added below command in config/application.rb and then it works

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
$ rails g model Account
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140205052957_create_accounts.rb
      create    app/models/account.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/account_spec.rb
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
```